# Subversion using SSPI module HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: svn, http, https, sspi

I'm upgrading our svn server and want to change to windows authentication instead of htpassword files.
I've installed the module and can get it running on **HTTP** or **HTTPS**.

Accessing the repos, using **TortoiseSVN**, I have 2 scenarios:

1. Accessing when **SSPI + HTTPS** is setup. Login is automatically and works like a charm :)
2. Accessing when **SSPI + HTTP** is setup. Login requires me to enter my domain username and password in TortoiseSVN, which is ok, as I can ask TortoiseSVN to remember my credentials.

> **My questions is:**
>
> If I use **SSPI + HTTP** instead of **SSPI + HTTPS** are my
>   password and username then encrypted?

The reason I'm asking is that we're on a LAN and will never be able to access from the outside and SSL is kindda overkill as it makes everything rather slow :S. *So I would prefer to use HTTP  + SSPI.*

I searched for my password on the network using WireShark and had no luck, which would mean that the credentials are indeed encrypted :). Could only find a line which I suspect is my user+pass that looked something like this:  Authorization: Basic Yh2_3 m%erTo_d4fre

*If anyone can clearify this for me or **better yet link me to a location which states that passwords ARE encrypted when using SSPI + HTTP**, I would be most gratefull :).*

Kind regards
Garrett

*************************************EDIT*******************************************

It seems i've misunderstod something very important. Please verify wether i'm right :):

> Accessing svn when SSPI+HTTP is
>   enabled, it actually means that SSPI
>   is disabled and that i'm using Basic
>   Auth when accessing, as SSPI **requires** SSL. Which means that my username and password only have the **mild Basic Auth encryption, nothing like SSL encryption.**
>
> The only place where the SSPI module enters the picture is that it receives the 
>   username+pass from Basic Auth and then it uses those to verify the user against the domain **(in
>   a secure manner of course ???)**.

This is what I could deduct when reading the documentation once again. Can anyone verify if I have gotten this right?

Kind regards

Garrett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The behavior changed in Subversion 1.8.0: now Subversion client automatically authenticate using SPNEGO/NTLM protocol if server supports it. I.e. default value for `http-auth-types` configuration option is `negotiate;ntlm;basic`

By default Subversion network library uses Negotiate/NTLM only for HTTPS connections.

Quoting VisualSVN Server [KB article](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00040/), which applicable for any Subversion client/server:
http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00040/

> To protect from eavesdroppers and man-in-the-middle attacks it's not recommended to use NTLM/Negotiate authentication over the unsecure HTTP protocol. That's why this option is disabled by default.
>
> But if you are forced to use the HTTP protocol, you can manually reconfigure Subversion clients. NTLM/Negotiate authentication over the HTTP protocol can be enabled using the **http-auth-types** Subversion configuration option. The default value for this option is "http-auth-types = basic". In order to allow NTLM/Negotiate authentication you should change this value to "http-auth-types = basic;negotiate".

The article also has step-by-step instructions how to change Subversion configuration.